# For which $a$ and $b$ has $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & a & b \\ a&0&b \end{bmatrix}$ the eigenvalues $0$ and $3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If the matrix
>   $$
> P = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & a & b \\
>  a & 0 & b
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   has eigenvalues $0$ and $3$ then to determine values of $a$ and $b$.

I know that $\det(P) = 0$ (because one eigenvalue is $0$) and got $a=0$ or $a=2b$. But how do I proceed from here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$0$ and $3$ are supposed to be eigenvalues of $P$, i.e. $\det(P) = 0 $ and $\det(P - 3 I) = 0$. From the first condition you've correctly deduced $a = 0$ or $a = 2b$.

If $a = 0$, then the second condition yields $b = 3$. If you plug $a =2b$ into the second equation, you get $-6b^2 + 24b - 18 = 0$, i.e. $b = 1$ or $b = 3$.